# Symfony 2 DoctrineMongoDBBundle generates strange queries

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-odm

I'm using DoctrineMongoDBBundle and want to get some records. In my repository class I have code:

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder()->field('categories.data')
    ->equals($categoryId)->getQuery()->execute();
```

In profiler's log it generates absolutely working query:

```
db.recipe.find({ "categories.data": 16 }).sort([ ]);
```

When I run this query via console client it returns me record. **But repository class get's nothing.**

My server's log looks like this:

```
query test_database.recipe query: { $query: { categories.data: "2" }, $orderby: {} } ntoreturn:0 keyUpdates:0 nreturned:0 reslen:20 0ms
```

But if i run plain PHP script to get same data:

```
<?php 
$mongo = new Mongo();
$col = $mongo->test_database->recipe;

foreach ($col->find(array("categories.data" => 2)) as $r) {
  print_r($r);
}
```

I got result and server's log looks like this:

```
query test_database.recipe query: { categories.data: 2 } ntoreturn:0 keyUpdates:0 nreturned:1 reslen:1037 0ms
```

so difference is:

> query test_database.recipe query: { **$query:** { categories.data: "2" }, **$orderby**: {} } ntoreturn:0 keyUpdates:0 **nreturned:0** reslen:20 0ms
>
> query test_database.recipe query: { categories.data: 2 } ntoreturn:0 keyUpdates:0 **nreturned:1** reslen:1037 0ms[/quote]

Checked both MongoDB 2.1.1 and 1.8.1, **deps** file:

```
[symfony]
    git=http://github.com/symfony/symfony.git
    version=origin/2.0

[doctrine-common]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/common.git
    version=2.2.2

[doctrine-dbal]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/dbal.git
    version=2.1.7

[doctrine]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2.git
    version=2.1.7

[doctrine-mongodb-odm]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm.git

[DoctrineMongoDBBundle]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoDBBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Symfony/Bundle/DoctrineMongoDBBundle
    version=origin/2.0
```

Comment: Seems like problem in dot notation. When I run flat query like: `->field('title')->equals(array('$regex' => 'Potato*'))` it returns objects and logs looks like:
`query test_database.recipe query: { $query: { title: { $regex: "Potato*" } }, $orderby: {} } ntoreturn:0 keyUpdates:0 nreturned:2 reslen:3680 0ms`

Comment: No, it is not. Seems like it is not working for searching in array values.

Comment: Please share your mapping for the Recipe document and whatever embedded document is being stored in the `categories` field (I assume that's an EmbedMany relationship).

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean mapping? Document class?
Categories field contains plain array: `> db.recipe.find({_id: ObjectId("501d736fd940d76b0f000002")}, {categories: true});` returns:
`{ "_id" : ObjectId("501d736fd940d76b0f000002"), "categories" : [ 2, 4, 17 ] }`

Comment: [Mapping](http://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#mapping-objects-onto-a-database) is either going to be XML, YAML or your document class with annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this log you shared:

> query test_database.recipe query: { $query: { categories.data: "2" },
>   $orderby: {} } ntoreturn:0 keyUpdates:0 nreturned:0 reslen:20 0ms
>
> query test_database.recipe query: { categories.data: 2 } ntoreturn:0
>   keyUpdates:0 nreturned:1 reslen:1037 0ms

You're matching by the string `"2"` in the first query, but the integer `2` in the second. These are not equivalent in MongoDB. Consider:

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.7
connecting to: test
> db.foo.drop()
false
> db.foo.insert({x:1})
> db.foo.find({x:"1"})
> db.foo.find({x:1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("502fb9f5b6b1fd9f6ea794a4"), "x" : 1 }
```

Have you tried casting `$categoryId` to an integer before using it in the query builder?